# A serious "ModuleNotFoundError: No module name..." problem

Tags: python-3.x, miniconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8qPZ.jpg)

As the image shows, I have marked the parent directory `source root`, and pycharm doesn't report an import-error(like wave line or something). In python console, even I can import the package`fedml_api`. But when I run it in the terminal, it tells that

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'fedml_api'
```

**BTW**, I am running a project in an activated virtual environment called `fedml`. But the first time I install the venv I made a mistake so that my venv folder is not in my project directory but in a higher one. I don't know whether this is the reason......

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem before.

Just cut fedml_api to the parent directory 'site-packages' that works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).